# Should I add E-books and Blog Posts to my CV?

Tags: cv

I am still planning to get into a Master's program sometime in the fall next year.  Should I add my E-books and Blog Posts to my CV?

I keep my blog posts formal and educational.  The following is a link to my blog: http://cybersecwise.com/wordpress/. I do already know people reviewing my CV will not actually read my blog.

I have also written two E-books.  One is called "NoSQL Injection for Elasticsearch", which was referenced in a Russian Defcon (Hacker Convention).  Since it was referenced in a defcon, does that count as Peer Reviewed?  The other E-book is called "Introduction to Web Hacking: Cross-site Scripting".

These things are all computer security related, but I am actually going to go for a Master's in Computer Science.

Comment: I would include them in a section titled "community engagement" or something of that flavor. Note that something being cited is not equivalent to peer-review, do not classify the work as peer-reviewed.

Comment: @ErikM Seems like a good answer to me, maybe make it an answer?

Comment: Someday everyone will stop using the stupid E- prefix.  E-mail is just mail.  E-commerce is just commerce.  E-books are just books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would include them in a section titled "community engagement" or something of that flavor.

Note that something being cited is not equivalent to peer-review, do not classify the work as peer-reviewed.

Comment: Do you think a title of "Extracurricular Activities" would be appropriate?

Comment: I think extracurricular activities is only a term that should be used if you are still in school, to differentiate the activities from school activities.